# Unknown custom element: <x-flex> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Tags: vue.js

How Do I resolve this. I am getting the error Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. This error is being printed on the console as I run the app.  When it does this , the nothing is displayed on  on the views its just blank.

```
<template>
    <v-container id="dashboard" fluid   grid-list-lg class="mx- pa-7">

        <v-layout  row wrap>
            <v-flex md3 sm6 xs12>
                <v-card class="cyan darken-3" l light>
                    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm light>
                        <v-layout class="mt-0 mb-0" row wrap>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs3>
                                <v-icon class="mx-0" x-large light>beenhere</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs9 >
                                <v-layout class="mt-2 mb-0 pa-0" row wrap>
                                    <x-flex d-flex xs12>

                                        <div class="silver--text subheading">Income Revenue</div>

                                    </x-flex>

                                    <v-flex d-flex xs12>
                                        <div class="silver--text display-1">{{totalUsers}}</div>
                                        <v-btn outline class="darkgrey--text darken-1" right flat small>More</v-btn>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex md3 sm6 xs12>
                <v-card class="blue-grey darken-1">
                    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm light>
                        <v-layout class="mt-0 mb-0" row wrap>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs3>
                                <v-icon class="mx-0" x-large light>beenhere</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs9 >
                                <v-layout class="mt-2 mb-0 pa-0" row wrap>
                                    <x-flex d-flex xs12>

                                        <div class="silver--text subheading">Today's Revenue</div>

                                    </x-flex>

                                    <v-flex d-flex xs12>
                                        <div class="silver--text display-1">{{totalAmount}}</div>
                                        <v-btn outline class="darkgrey--text darken-1" right flat small>More</v-btn>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex md3 sm6 xs12>
                <v-card class="pink  lighten-4">
                    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm light>
                        <v-layout class="mt-0 mb-0" row wrap>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs3>
                                <v-icon class="mx-0" x-large light>beenhere</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs9 >
                                <v-layout class="mt-2 mb-0 pa-0" row wrap>
                                    <x-flex d-flex xs12>

                                        <div class="silver--text subheading">Yesterday's Revenue</div>

                                    </x-flex>

                                    <v-flex d-flex xs12>
                                        <div class="silver--text display-1">{{totalUsersThis}}</div>
                                        <v-btn outline class="darkgrey--text darken-1" right flat small>More</v-btn>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex md3 sm6 xs12>
                <v-card class="blue-grey darken-1">
                    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm light>
                        <v-layout class="mt-0 mb-0" row wrap>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs3>
                                <v-icon class="mx-0" x-large light>beenhere</v-icon>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex d-flex xs9 >
                                <v-layout class="mt-2 mb-0 pa-0" row wrap>
                                    <x-flex d-flex xs12>

                                        <div class="silver--text subheading">This Week's Revenue</div>

                                    </x-flex>

                                    <v-flex d-flex xs12>
                                        <div class="silver--text display-1">{{totalAmountThis}}</div>
                                        <v-btn outline class="darkgrey--text darken-1" right flat small>More</v-btn>
                                    </v-flex>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>


        </v-layout>


        <v-layout class="pt-1" row wrap>
            <v-flex md4 xs12>
                <v-card light>
                    <doughnut></doughnut>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4 xs12>
                <v-card light>
                    <bar></bar>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4 xs12>
                <v-card light class="Chart">
                    <line-chart></line-chart>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

        </v-layout>

        <v-layout>
            <v-flex xs7>
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>
                        Recent Transactions
                        <v-spacer/>  <v-spacer/>
                        <v-text-field name="product" label="Search" light v-model="searchTransaction"></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers" v-bind:items="items" v-bind:search="search"
                                  v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination" hide-actions
                                  class="elevation-1">
                        <template  slot="items" slot-scope="props" class="body-2" >
                            <td class="body-2"  >{{ props.item.account_from }}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.amount }}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.transaction_code}}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.payment_mode}}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.ref}}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.status}}

                            </td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.date}}</td>
                            <!--   <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.quantity}}</td>
                               <td class="text-xs-left"><img :src='getImageURL(props.item.Product.phone_number)' height="90dp" width="90dp"/></td>
                               <td class="text-xs-left">
                                   <v-btn fab small dark class="teal" @click.native="edit()">
                                       <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
                                   </v-btn>
                                   <v-btn fab small class="cyan" @click.native="remove(props.item)">
                                       <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
                                   </v-btn>
                               </td>-->
                        </template>
                    </v-data-table>
                    <div class="text-xs-center pt-2">
                        <v-pagination v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages" circle></v-pagination>
                    </div>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex xs5>
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>
                        Merchants
                        <v-spacer/>  <v-spacer/>
                        <v-text-field name="product" label="Search" light v-model="productSearch"></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers2" v-bind:items="businesses" v-bind:search="search"
                                  v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination2" hide-actions
                                  class="elevation-1"
                                  :loading="false">
                        <v-progress-linear slot="progress" color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
                        <template  slot="items" slot-scope="props" class="body-2" >
                            <td class="body-2"  >{{ props.item.business_name }}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.short_code }}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.sender_id}}</td>
                            <!--<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.payment_mode}}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">KES {{ props.item.transaction_ref}}</td>
                            <td class="text-xs-left">KES {{ props.item.date}}</td>-->
                            <!--   <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.quantity}}</td>
                               <td class="text-xs-left"><img :src='getImageURL(props.item.Product.phone_number)' height="90dp" width="90dp"/></td>
                               <td class="text-xs-left">
                                   <v-btn fab small dark class="teal" @click.native="edit()">
                                       <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
                                   </v-btn>
                                   <v-btn fab small class="cyan" @click.native="remove(props.item)">
                                       <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
                                   </v-btn>
                               </td>-->
                        </template>
                    </v-data-table>
                    <div class="text-xs-center pt-2">
                        <v-pagination v-model="pagination2.page" :length="pages2" circle></v-pagination>
                    </div>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>

        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
    import Bar from "../components/chart/Bar";
    import Doughnut from "../components/chart/Doughnut";
    import LineChart from "../components/chart/LineChart";
    import { execute } from '../api'
    export default {
        name: "Dashboard",
        components: {
            Bar,
            Doughnut,
            LineChart
        },
        data () {
            return {
                searchTransaction:'',
                items:[],
                businesses:[],
                totalUsers:'',
                totalAmount:'',
                totalUsersThis:'',
                totalAmountThis:'',
                search: '',
                pagination: [],
                pagination2: [],
                productSearch:'',
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: 'Phone Number',
                        left: true,
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'phone_number'
                    },
                    { text: 'Amount', value: 'amount' , sortable: false,},
                    { text: 'Transaction Code', value: 'transaction_code' , sortable: false,},
                    { text: 'Payment Mode', value: 'payment_mode' , sortable: false},
                    { text: 'Transaction ref', value: 'transaction_ref' , sortable: false},
                    { text: 'Status', value: 'status' , sortable: false},
                    { text: 'date', value: 'date' , sortable: false}
                ], headers2: [
                    {
                        text: 'Business',
                        left: true,
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'business'
                    },
                    { text: 'ShortCode', value: 'short_code' , sortable: false,},
                    { text: 'Sender ID', value: 'sender_id' , sortable: false,},

                ]
            };
        },
        watch: {
            searchTransaction: function() {
                this.getTransactions();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getCustomers () {
                const data = new FormData()
                data.append('TransactionType', 'getDashboardData')

                execute(data).then((res) => {
                    this.totalUsers= new Intl.NumberFormat().format(res.data.data.IncomeRevenue)
                    this.totalAmount= new Intl.NumberFormat().format(res.data.data.TodayRevenue)
                    this.totalUsersThis= new Intl.NumberFormat().format(res.data.data.YesterdayRevenue)
                    this.totalAmountThis= new Intl.NumberFormat().format(res.data.data.ThisWeekRevenue)
                }).catch((e) => {
                    // TODO
                })
            },
            getTransactions () {
                const data = new FormData()
                data.append('TransactionType', 'getRecentTransactions')
                data.append('keyword',this.searchTransaction)
                execute(data).then((res) => {
                    this.items = res.data.data
                }).catch((e) => {
                    // TODO
                })
            }, getBusinesses () {
                const data = new FormData()
                data.append('TransactionType', 'getBusinesses')
                execute(data).then((res) => {
                    this.businesses = res.data.data
                }).catch((e) => {
                    // TODO
                })
            }
        },
        computed: {
            pages () {
                return this.pagination && this.pagination.rowsPerPage ? Math.ceil(this.pagination.totalItems / this.pagination.rowsPerPage) : 0
            },
            pages2 () {
                return this.pagination2 && this.pagination2.rowsPerPage ? Math.ceil(this.pagination2.totalItems / this.pagination2.rowsPerPage) : 0
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getCustomers()
            this.getTransactions()
            this.getBusinesses()
        }
    };
</script>
<!--<style  scoped>
    #dashboard .flex {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
</style>-->
```

Comment: Well, did you register the `x-flex` component? Seems like Vue doesn't know it. Where do you expect it to come from?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using lots of `<v-flex>` elements in your code, my guess is you just made a typo and accidentally created a `<x-flex>` element. Just fix the typo (change all the `x-flex` to `v-flex` in your code) and it will work